# Why pip3 install in python2 sitepackages

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

First I use

```
Python 3.6.5
Python 2.7.14
and mac.
```

In my case, I just download module like `numpy`(for example, and other's same) when i use `pip3` it said like..
[image]

and pip is same.

but when I use it, in `python3`[image]

In `python2`, It working well...
[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: What's the output of `which pip3`? You're installing the package on Pyhton-2.7.

Comment: Please do not add images of plain text when the text itself should suffice.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems that `pip3`  refers to Python-2.7's pip module or any other version of Python-3 that you have installed on your machine. However, you can install packages directly using the intended Python version. You'd need to just use `-m` option.

```
python3.6 -m pip install numpy
```

Another option is to changing the source path that `pip3` refers to. You can do this by finding the path of Python-3.6's pip and just bind it to `pip3` alias.

Comment: how can one change the source path of pip3 and re bind it?

Comment: @JonathanIshii That process is described in the other answer.

Answer (score 12):

Find the absolute path of the `python3` interpreter with a command like this:

```
$ which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python
```

Your path may be something different, of course.  Copy that line to your clipboard.

Edit the `pip3` script, which was installed using incorrect interpreter. Something like this:

```
vi $(which pip3)
```

You might need to use `sudo` here, but try it first without.  The first line will be something like:

```
#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

Change it to the path found in the previous step, e.g.

```
#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python
```

Save the `pip3` file and exit. This should be sufficient to associate `pip3` with the correct environment. Check and verify the result with `pip3 --version`.  Now `pip3 install numpy` should work as expected.

Comment: This solved it! For me the reference was `#!/usr/local/bin/python3`

Answer (score 6):

This works for me:

```
python3 -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip
```