# from matplotlib.pyplot import plt ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, linux-mint

I'm on linux mint 18.3. I can import matplotlib fine, but I need to plot something from a certain file. When I try to plot something simple, I get this error:

```
python3 spline.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "spline.py", line 2, in <module>
from matplotlib.pyplot import plt
ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

my code in the file is:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import plt

plt.plot([1, 2, 3],[2, 4, 6])

plt.show()
```

already tried:

```
pip install matplotlib
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
```

Comment: did you check pythonpath?

Comment: It seems you have installed matplotlib in a different environment than you use when running the file. Else, your problem might be similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51055429/why-pip3-install-in-python2-sitepackages) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31407208/pip3-4-v-refers-to-python2-7-installation).

Answer (score 0):

I think in your code you should use

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind guys the thing was the way I was importing it, the "correct" way is:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

that's all now it's working